Assigning Physics To Multiple Objects
When I attempt to select all objects in a collection to assign the same physics to the objects, it doesn't seem to assign to every object. In fact, it either assigns it to one or none of the objects.
I am trying to make a scene with many animated objects, I can't believe that I would have to select every object individually and assign the physics individually. Would anyone know what I might be doing wrong? If you need more info about it, please let me know.

Press Alt while you assign physics to multiple objects.

@HarryMcKenzie If "assign physics" in this case means clicking on the respective button in the Physics tab, then holding Alt while you click to assign it to multiple objects does not work in Blender 4.1 and older versions, and in 4.2 it still does not work for Force Field, Rigid Body and Rigid Body Constraint though.

...reading the question again I was just wondering: are you talking about animations or physics simulations? Those are not the same things.

I was trying to assign active rigid body physics to some objects. Thank you for the clarification that ALT won't work while applying rigid body physics.
